# Java Delta Time causes jerky movement

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, timedelta

I'm trying to calculate delta time in order to move a circle smoothly across the screen no matter the frame rate. When I run my code, the circle jerks which means that the delta time is not calculated correctly but I can't find the error in my calculations. Here is the code

The Main Class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static long lastTime;
    public static double deltaTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lastTime = 0;

        //Setting up the JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.add(new PanelP());        
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Loop
        while(true) {
            //Calculate DeltaTime
            deltaTime = (lastTime - (lastTime = System.nanoTime())) / -1000000.0;
            //Draw Frame
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

And the Panel class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelP extends JPanel{

    private float x;

    public PanelP() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //Move circle
        x += (10 * (float)Main.deltaTime);

        //Draw Circle
        g.drawOval(Math.round(x), 50, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably test for `deltaTime` == 0 because the first time you try that calculation the time won't compute correctly.

Comment: I tried this but even after the first delta time calculation, jerky movement is still observed.

Comment: A painting method is for painting only. Don't change the properties of the class in the painting method. You should have a method like setOvalX(...) to set the location where you want to paint the circle. You also should not be using a "while (true)" loop. For animation you should be using a Swing Timer. You should not be repainting the frame. You only need to repaint the panel since that is where you custom painting code is.

Comment: Well `lastTime = 0;` is probably a bug so I would fix it.  You're also updating as fast as humanly possible.  I'd use a SwingTimer or even just Tread.sleep() to slow things down so the screen has time to actually display. Try for 20 times per second to start.

Comment: @markspace Thanks, that worked. If you submit your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `lastTime = 0;` is probably a bug so I would fix it. Initialize it with `System.nanoTime()` instead.
2. You're also updating as fast as humanly possible. I'd use a `SwingTimer` or even just `Tread.sleep()` to slow things down so the screen has time to actually display. Try for 20 times per second to start.